# Why AWS RDS doesn't update minor version?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I have a small RDS instance on AWS, and on the maintenance details I have set "Auto minor version upgrade" to Yes. But I still have the MySQL engine version 5.5.27, and AWS has  the version 5.5.33 available. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Have you had auto minor upgrade turned on all along, or did you enable it only recently?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot it's been turned on all along, more than a year ago.

Comment: I'm having the same issue with two RDS instances that are currently on 5.7.19. AWS is telling me I should update to 5.7.23 however I've had the auto upgrade setting enabled since these instances were first deployed!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have a couple of out of sight, out of mind 5.5 instances in RDS, and it turns out they are running 5.5.27 as well.

Between 5.5.27 and the highest currently-available version, 5.5.33, RDS for MySQL 5.5 only (apparently) supported one other minor release, which was 5.5.31.

RDS originally [posted a schedule](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ann.jspa?annID=2176) of when minor version upgrades to 5.5.33 would be done, and they [subsequently announced they had suspended](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ann.jspa?annID=2209) those automatic upgrades:

> On 30th October 2013, based on signals we received from our monitoring systems, we paused the upgrade process in all the Regions. We will review the system and post a new schedule for the upgrades in the future.

This should explain why your system wasn't upgraded to 5.5.33, but it doesn't explain why you weren't upgraded to 5.5.31... or why I wasn't.

Then I realized that I don't actually remember an announcement about automatic upgrades to 5.5.31.

I searched for it, and didn't find it.

I did, however find [the announcement of scheduled automatic upgrades to 5.5.27](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ann.jspa?annID=1787).

This leads me to speculate that RDS never actually did a mass upgrade to 5.5.31 like they did to 5.5.27 or will presumably still be doing to 5.5.33... in which case, the state of your instances, and my instances, makes sense.  I've searched pretty diligently and come up with no other explanations.  The AWS forum is also very low on search results when it comes to any questions referencing 5.5.31 at all.  I have also not been able to encounter any other "unsuspected settings" that would have stopped automatic minor version upgrades.

So I don't think you're missing something, I suspect that you will be automatically upgraded to 5.5.33 when they resume the automatic upgrades.  My plan is to wait, and if the upgrades roll around and I don't get mine, post to the forums.

The only other options, it seems like, would be to post to the forums now, to see if you can get an AWS person's attention or feedback from any users with suggestions... or to manually select the new minor version and apply it to your instance, though that won't serve to answer the question of whether minor version upgrades are broken, or whether what we're currently seeing is pretty much what we should be seeing, on systems running 5.5.27.

Answer (score 5):

This question is quite old now, this answer explains a situation where this behaviour occurs in 2019 with the postgres `9.6.*` engine version.

First lets look at the last few available `minor` engine versions:

```
$ aws rds describe-db-engine-versions --engine postgres --engine-version 9.6.8 | \
jq '.DBEngineVersions[0].ValidUpgradeTarget[] | select(.IsMajorVersionUpgrade==false)'
{
  "Engine": "postgres",
  "EngineVersion": "9.6.9",
  "AutoUpgrade": false,
  "IsMajorVersionUpgrade": false
}
{
  "Engine": "postgres",
  "EngineVersion": "9.6.10",
  "Description": "PostgreSQL 9.6.10-R1",
  "AutoUpgrade": false,
  "IsMajorVersionUpgrade": false
}
{
  "Engine": "postgres",
  "EngineVersion": "9.6.11",
  "Description": "PostgreSQL 9.6.11-R1",
  "AutoUpgrade": true,
  "IsMajorVersionUpgrade": false
}
{
  "Engine": "postgres",
  "EngineVersion": "9.6.12",
  "Description": "PostgreSQL 9.6.12-R1",
  "AutoUpgrade": false,
  "IsMajorVersionUpgrade": false
}
{
  "Engine": "postgres",
  "EngineVersion": "9.6.14",
  "Description": "PostgreSQL 9.6.14-R1",
  "AutoUpgrade": false,
  "IsMajorVersionUpgrade": false
}
{
  "Engine": "postgres",
  "EngineVersion": "9.6.15",
  "Description": "PostgreSQL 9.6.15-R1",
  "AutoUpgrade": false,
  "IsMajorVersionUpgrade": false
}
```

Notice that *only* `9.6.11` has `AutoUpgrade` set to `true`. This means that if you are running a version prior to `9.6.11` *and* you have `AutoMinorVersionUpgrade` set to `true` *then* you will be automatically upgraded to `9.6.11` during your next maintenance window.

If you are running `9.6.11` you will *not* be automatically upgraded to subsequent versions. This is despite the RDS console recommending the following:

> Your DB instance is running postgres version 9.6.11. We recommend that you upgrade to version 9.6.15 because it contains the latest security fixes and other improvements.

Useful commands:

```
$ aws rds describe-db-instances | jq -r '.DBInstances[0].EngineVersion'
$ aws rds describe-db-instances | jq -r '.DBInstances[0].AutoMinorVersionUpgrade'
$ aws rds describe-db-instances | jq -r '.DBInstances[0].PreferredMaintenanceWindow'
$ aws rds describe-pending-maintenance-actions
```